# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'img')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fileupload

tengo un error al subir una imagen mediante un modal , la imagen sube correctamente pero la respuesta me retorna asi
ya intente de todo pero lo unico que se me ocurre es mandar un eventemiter desde el servicio y jugar con eso pero no seria lo optimo ya que quiero solucionar este error (resaltar que el backend no tiene problemas)
quiza el codigo esta engorroso pero le dejo mi repositorio
https://github.com/DevMeans/Front-merch
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

este es mi componente // modal.ts

```
     subirImagen() {
        this.fileUploadService.actualizarFoto(this.imagenSubir, this.modalImagenService.coleccion, this.modalImagenService.usuario.uid).then(
          img => {
            this.usuario.img = img
            Swal.fire('Guardado', 'Cambios realizados con exito', 'success')
            //  this.modalImagenService.nuevaImagen.emit(img)
            this.modalImagenService.ocutalModal
          }
        ).catch(err => {
          //al parece que no detecta a tiempo el error 
          console.log(err)
          this.modalImagenService.ocutalModal
        })
      }
//modal.html

   <input type="file" name="" id="" (change)="cambiarImagen($event.target)" accept="image/*">
```

este es el servicio de mi modal

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalImagenService {
  public _ocultarModal: string = 'none'
  public img = ''
  public usuario: any
  public coleccion: 'usuarios' | 'productos' | 'categorias' = 'usuarios'
  public nuevaImagen: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>()
  constructor() { }
  get ocutalModal() {
    return this._ocultarModal = 'none'
  }
  abrirModal(usuario: any, tipo: 'usuarios' | 'productos' | 'categorias') {
    console.log(tipo)
    this._ocultarModal = 'block'
    this.img = usuario.img
    this.usuario = usuario
    this.coleccion = tipo
  }
}

este es el servicio para subir la imagen
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
const base_url = environment.base_url
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileUploadService {

  constructor() { }
  async actualizarFoto(
    archivo: File,
    tipo:'usuarios'|'productos'| 'categorias',
    id: string

  ) {
    try {
      const url = `${base_url}/subirimagen/${tipo}/${id}`
      const formdData = new FormData();
      formdData.append('img', archivo);
      const resp = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'x-token': localStorage.getItem('token') || ''
        },
        body: formdData
      })
      const data = await resp.json()
      //  return 'Data'
      if (data.ok) {
        return data.results.img
      } else {
        console.log(data.msg)
        return false
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

y este es el componente categoria.ts

```
 abrirModal(categoria:any){
    this.modalImagenServices.abrirModal(categoria,'categorias')
  }
```

categoria.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <div class="car-body">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Buscar Usuario" class="form-control"
                (keyup)="buscar(txttermino.value)" #txttermino>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="cargando">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info text-center">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Cargando</h4>
            <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
            <p class="mb-0">Por favor espere</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="!cargando">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="text-center d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="crearCategoria()">CrearUsuario</button>
                </div>

                <h4 class="card-title">total de usuarios</h4>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="w-100x">avatar</th>
                                <th>nombre</th>
                                <th>estado</th>>
                                <th class="text-nowrap w-100x">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let categoria of categorias">
                                <td>
                                    <img (click)="abrirModal(categoria)" [src]="categoria.img" alt="img"
                                        class="img-ref img-circle">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de categoria"
                                        [(ngModel)]="categoria.nombre">
                                </td>
                                <td><select [(ngModel)]="categoria.estado" class="form-control"
                                        (change)="editarEstadoCategoria(categoria)">
                                        <option [value]="true">activado</option>
                                        <option [value]="false">desactivado</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td class="text-nowrap">
                                    <a (click)="editarCategoria(categoria)" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        data-original-title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Close"
                                        (click)="eliminarCategoria(categoria)"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div *ngIf="txttermino.value.length===0">
                        <button (click)="cambiarPagina(-5)" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">atras</button>
                        <button (click)="cambiarPagina(5)" class="btn btn-primary">siguiente</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El error parece decir que this.usuario es undefined

Comment: Y en efecto, tal como menciona Pablo Lozano, `usuario` se declara al principio de la clase y luego se implementa en el constructor, sin embargo, no se inicializa, por lo que ha de ser `undefined` al momento de ser llamado, ya que, literalmente, no se ha definido su valor.